# ¿Por qué al hacer una comparación entre 2 arrays 2 veces me trae datos diferentes php?

Tags: php

Tengo 2 arreglos y al hacer comparaciones primero de una forma y después inversa me trae datos diferentes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->modelConfBitacoraCambios WHERE id_cliente = :id:";
        $model = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($sql, ['id'=>$idCliente])->toArray();

        $datosModificados = [];
        foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
            $arr_ant = json_decode($value['dato_anterior'], TRUE);
            $arr_nue = json_decode($value['dato_nuevo'], TRUE);

            $result_array_anterior = array_diff($arr_ant,$arr_nue);

            $result_array_nuevo = array_diff($arr_nue,$arr_ant);

            $datosModificados[$key]['fecha_modificacion'] = $value['fecha_creacion'];
            $datosModificados[$key]['usuario_modificacion'] = $value['usuario_creacion'];
            if ($result_array_anterior != []) {
                $datosModificados[$key]["dato_anterior"] = $result_array_anterior;
                $datosModificados[$key]["dato_nuevo"] = $result_array_nuevo;
            }
        }
```

Los JSON son los siguientes ya y las diferencias son solo 3 datos: clave_clasificacion, clave_forma_de_pago y clave_territorio:

```
{
    "amount": "0.0000",
    "clave_agrupacion": "Z003",
    "clave_clasificacion": "02",
    "clave_esquema": "1",
    "clave_forma_de_pago": "CCON",
    "clave_grupocuentas": "2100",
    "clave_imputacion": "02",
    "clave_segmento": "BA",
    "clave_territorio": "AS",
    "estado": "1",
    "iddef_cliente": "68472180",
    "iddef_direccion_tipo": "1",
    "iddef_organizacion": "1",
    "iddef_tipo_cliente": "1",
    "interfaz_opera": 1,
    "replicar_finanzas": "1",
    "usuario_creacion": "jalcantar",
    "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "lugomez"}

    {
    "amount": "0.0000",
    "clave_agrupacion": "Z003",
    "clave_clasificacion": "01",
    "clave_esquema": "1",
    "clave_forma_de_pago": "C007",
    "clave_grupocuentas": "2100",
    "clave_imputacion": "02",
    "clave_segmento": "BA",
    "clave_territorio": "USA",
    "estado": "1",
    "iddef_cliente": "68472180",
    "iddef_direccion_tipo": "1",
    "iddef_organizacion": "1",
    "iddef_tipo_cliente": "1",
    "interfaz_opera": 1,
    "replicar_finanzas": "1",
    "usuario_creacion": "jalcantar",
    "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "lugomez"
}
```

Salida es la siguiente y como se puede ver en el primero trae las 3 diferencias y en el segundo solo trae 2 diferencias:

```
{"dato_anterior": {
    "clave_territorio": "USA",
    "clave_clasificacion": "01",
    "clave_forma_de_pago": "C007"
},
"dato_nuevo": {
    "clave_territorio": "AS",
    "clave_forma_de_pago": "CCON"
}}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que hay en `$value` exactamente?

Comment: @A.Cedano se supone que `$value['dato_anterior']` y `$value['dato_nuevo']` deben tener guardodo los `JSON` en formato `String` a lo que el les hace el  `json_decode`

Comment: no te muestra el resultado como lo deseas porque primero debemos entender como funciona [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php). Compara array1 con uno o más arrays y devuelve los valores de array1 que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros arrays.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez eso lo supongo, pero sin ver el contenido de los datos con los que se está trabajando, que es el punto de partida de todo, es imposible reproducir el problema.

Comment: Por otra  parte, viendo en la nueva edición que los datos vienen de la base de datos, me pregunto por qué mareas tanto los datos, primero consultando, luego convirtiendo a array, luego convirtiendo a json, y luego de nuuuueeeeeevo convirtiendo a array y , luego comparando ¿? ¿No era mejor, de entrada, traer los datos organizados como los necesitas?

Comment: @A.Cedano el tema no es de donde viene los datos; eso es adorno; con el ejemplo del contenido del JSON es suficiente.

Comment: edite la pregunta y agregue de donde viene $value, $value['dato_anterior'] y $value['dato_nuevo']  son dos campos de una tabla y son JSON y los convierto a array para hacer el array diff

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez los datos son importantes para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Luis, ¿la respuesta de @aeportugal resuelve tu problema? Si no lo resuelve, recomiendo que nos indiques un pequeño ejemplo del set de datos que traería la consulta para poder ayudarte mejor. De todos modos, sigo pensando que en tu código se da demasiadas vueltas con tus datos y que haría falta optimizar.

Comment: lo que pasa es que los datos son 2 JSON guardados en una base de datos y vienen como JSON es decir $value['dato_nuevo'] y $value['dato_anterior'] son JSON asi que los convierto a un array con json_decode para hacer el array_diff, ahora bien si funciona la solucion de @aeportugal.

Comment: Puede que también funcione bien comparando como objetos JSON, sin convertir a array, eso se hace pasando solamente el valor a `json_decode()`, sin el `TRUE` al final. Si son estructuras parecidas debería funcionar solo con array_diff, eso depende de la estructura que tengan los datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php) solo compara valores, sin considerar las claves. Si encuentra el mismo valor en un key de `$arr1` en otro key de `$arr2` lo va a validar como datos iguales.

Para hacer la comparación estricta, índice contra índice, solo cambia a [array_diff_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

```
$result_array_anterior = array_diff_assoc($arr_ant,$arr_nue);
$result_array_nuevo = array_diff_assoc($arr_nue,$arr_ant);
```